# How to check where it page is going to redirect to

Tags: redirect, playframework, functional-testing

Play framework functional test

```
    public class MyFunctionalTest extends FunctionalTest {

        Http.Response response = GET( "/page1");

        assertStatus(302/*REDIRECT*/, response);

        ///TODO: check where it redirects to
...
```

How to check where it will redirect to? which url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check for the location-header:

```
assertEquals("/yourExpectedTarget", response.getHeader("Location"));
```

Comment: +1 You can also use Router.reverse() if you want Play to calculate the paths for you: `assertEquals( Router.reverse("Controller.method").url, response.getHeader("Location") );`